# ¿Cómo hacer que un campo auto-calculado me regrese valores con dos decimales?

Tags: python, web2py

Tengo esta tabla en web2py:

```
db.define_table('gastos_generales',
                Field('numero_ticket_gasto', 'string'),
                Field('tipo_centro_costo', 'reference tipos_centros_costos',requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.tipos_centros_costos, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('numero_centro_costo_proyecto', 'string'),
                Field('fecha_ticket_gasto', 'date'),
                Field('tipo_pago', 'reference tipos_pagos',requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.tipos_pagos, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('moneda', 'reference monedas',requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.monedas, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('detalle_ticket_gasto', 'string'),
                Field('detraccion', 'boolean'),
                Field('porcentaje_detraccion', 'double'),
                Field('total_venta', 'double'),
                Field('monto_detraccion', compute=lambda r: round(r['total_venta'] * r['porcentaje_detraccion'])),
                Field('fecha_recepcion', 'date'),
                Field('monto_sub_total', 'float'),
                Field('monto_impuesto', 'float'),
                Field('monto_total_gasto', 'float'),
                Field('nota', 'string'),
                format='%(numero_ticket_gasto)s')
```

El campo `monto_detraccion` es el resultado de `total_venta` por `porcentaje_detraccion`, pero no quiero que me redondee el valor sino que me salga con dos dígitos decimales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no le pasas el segundo parámetro (la cantidad de los dígitos) a la función [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round), entonces no te va a mostrar decimales.

Si necesitas, por ejemplo, dos decimales puedes modificar el campo asi:

```
db.define_table('gastos_generales',
    # ...
    Field('monto_detraccion', compute=lambda r: round(r['total_venta'] * r['porcentaje_detraccion'], 2)),
    # ...
)
```

Aunque si estás trabajando con decimales, lo ideal es que trabajes con el módulo [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), en web2py tendrías que cambiar los campos de `double` a `decimal(n, m)`.

Mira los [Field types](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-types).